# linux shell: sed regex working with special char

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

In my directory, there are some html files contains such a string:

```
sceneFilePath: "./video/video/960.mp4",
```

What I need to do is to replace the path above with the right path. So I write a script to do that:

```
find ./video -type f -name "*.mp4" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' myfile; do
    tmp=$(basename "$myfile")   #example.mp4
    tmp="${tmp/.mp4/.html}"
    # Here I create a file named $tmp according to a template with the command `cp`
    cp -rf index.html "$tmp"
    sed -i '' "s#sceneFilePath:.*,#sceneFilePath: \"${myfile}\",#g" "$tmp"
done
```

But it doesn't work.

Here is an example of `$myfile`:
`./video/Bentota & Hikkaduwa/Hotels/River House/River House - Balapitiya.mp4`

It seems that it is because of the `$myfile`, which contains some special characters, such as , `&`, `-`, or that it is because the `.*` can't match `./video/video/960.mp4`.

Comment: Is your filename ending with `.mp4` or `.html`?

Comment: @anubhava  oh I made a mistake. I'll update the question.

Comment: @anubhava  I don't understand your question. `sed` is working on the copied html file.

Comment: Concerning `.*`: I tried this: `echo "Hello, hello, hello, hello" | sed "s#ello.*,#ola,#g"`. The result is `Hola, hello` (because the `.*` is greedy).

Comment: You're going to continuously run into problems using sed and shell variables. Just use awk or perl and pass the variable to it.

Comment: If you're going to use sed, then do what it says in the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001. Note that contrary to the answers you've got do far, `&` is not your only problem character. Alternatively just use awk since awk can operate on literal strings and then you don't have to worry about any of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try something:

```
sed -e "s#sceneFilePath:.*,#fooFilePath: \"${myfile}\",#" index.html
```

results in

```
fooFilePath: "./video/Bentota sceneFilePath: "./video/video/960.mp4", Hikkaduwa/Hotels/River House/River House - Balapitiya.mp4",
```

So it matches the sceneFilePath line, replaces it, then inserts the matched content, then adds the rest of the replacement. Why?

From the sed manpage

```
   s/regexp/replacement/
          Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If  success‐
          ful,   replace  that  portion  matched  with  replacement.   The
          replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that
          portion  of  the  pattern  space  which matched, and the special
          escapes \1 through \9 to refer  to  the  corresponding  matching
          sub-expressions in the regexp.
```

So Your & is not escaped and inserts the matched scheneFilePath:.*, I'd try to escape it with something like

```
rep=${myfile//&/\\&}
sed -i "s#sceneFilePath:.*,#sceneFilePath: \"${rep}\",#g" "${tmp}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your `sed` command to this:

```
sed -i '' "s#sceneFilePath:.*#sceneFilePath: \"${myfile//&/\\&}\",#" "$tmp"
```

This will escape each occurrence of `&` so that `&` looses it's special meaning in replacement. Unescaped `&` in replacement is back-reference of the full match in the substitution pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk:

```
myfile="$myfile" awk -i inplace 'match($0,/(.*sceneFilePath:).*/,a) {$0=a[1] "\"" ENVIRON["myfile"] "\""} 1' "$tmp"
```

That will work for ANY characters in `$myfile` since it's just doing a literal string operation. It uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and, less importantly, inplace editing.